# Using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, childbrowser

My web application is a banking application. After entering application URL in IE browser, it checks for browser configuration/resolution in that browser and immediately opens another browser which has the actual application without any Address Bar. I'm trying to `switchTo` window and identify elements in browser two (where application is loaded).

`switchTo` window is not working in my case. How to identify elements from this new window? Please help.

EDIT: I even tried switching to 2nd browser based on title of the browser. Still its not working.

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C://Apps//IEDriverServernew.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.get("https://argoqa.snv.net");
        Thread.sleep(8000);


        String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
        //the above for loop iterates only once. shows only one window handle.

        driver.switchTo().frame("iframeContent"); // 2nd Browser has frame.

        Select bank = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("selectRegionID"))); //trying to select bank
        bank.selectByVisibleText("TEST BANK");

        System.out.println("Selenium Webdriver Script");
        driver.quit();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the second window auto-opened? Maybe you can create a while loop to wait for second window popuped. Then switch to it.

Comment: How is that new window identified in Task Manager? Is it still IE browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the registry for IE as shown below, and verify if the new window is detected.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

Right-click → New → String Value → Value name: TabProcGrowth (create if not exist)

TabProcGrowth (right-click) → Modify... → Value data: 0

Comment: @rajeshk If the answer was helpful, please accept the answer. Thank you